# Why getting timeout expired error even set Command Timeout as 0?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

In my case, I've written a tool to generate report from sql server result.
Having a stored procedure to get result from database. Used ADO.NET for accessing sql server database and set command timeout as 0 (sqlcommand.commandtimeout = 0) by value getting from app.config.
Command timeout represents 0 as infinite to run the query.

Even after set command timeout as 0, i'm getting below error,

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
```

code:

```
try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommandTimeout"]);
                        cmd.CommandText = "MyProc";

                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(ds, "TableName");
                    }
                }

                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

App.config

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyDBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2008R2INST; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=MyDB"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="CommandTimeout" value="0"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Can anybody know the reason why getting timeout expired error even i set command timeout as 0?

Comment: You should paste the stacktrace. There are more timeouts in effect that could have caused this (transaction, connection-timeout, network, etc.).

Comment: Is it possible that not the command itself but the connection throws the timeout? Try extending your connectionstring by ";Connection Timeout=0"